# Print ".pdf" file - PrinterJob

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I'm having problems when trying to print a ".pdf". I printed Strings with this code without problems, but the pdf will not.

My program receives a byte[] with pdf and print it, I thought of recording a tempfile to print from InputStream, but also failed.

Follows the code I'm using to print:

```
    FileChannel fc = null;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdf);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    RandomAccessFile fis = null;
    try {
        File Tempfile = File.createTempFile("portfolios-temp", ".pdf");

        fos = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
        fos.write(pdf);

        fos.close();

        FileInputStream psStream = new FileInputStream(tempfile);

        DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        MyDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add (new Copies (1));
        aset.add (OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
        aset.add (Sides.ONE_SIDED);
        aset.add (MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);

        DocPrintJob job printService.createPrintJob =();
        try {
            job.print (myDoc, aset);
        } Catch (Exception pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace ();
        }
    } [...]
```

I get the Print Service this way:

```
        PrintService printService = null;
        for(PrintService printServiceCurrent : PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices()) {
            if(printServiceCurrent.getName().equals(PRINTER_NAME)) {
                printService = printServiceCurrent;
                break;
            }
        }
```

He send a command to the printer, but comes like have no content. I checked the temporary file and it is being generated perfectly.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset HashPrintRequestAttributeSet = new();
```

it should be

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
```

Second you're not checking the printers  that can print the format according to the instructions in the attribute set.

Check this link for more detailed information:

[Java Print Service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/jpsOverview.fm4.html)

Comment: I added the code that I get the Print Service. I've also fixed the code of aset. Thanks